# This function is not working and I can not figure out why

Tags: python

I am creating a text-based game for a school project. I am a novice and found a pretty good YouTube tutorial. I am following along in the beginning pretty closely so that I may understand better. I've entered this code almost identical to what the tutorial has stated and the code in the tutorial works but mine does not. What am I doing wrong? My output is as follows...

```
Would you like to start the game? Y/N: Y

<function intro at 0x000001F74F2DF040>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

```
def intro():
    print('There are 8 buildings that consist of a Supermarket, a Restaurant, a Convenience Store,')
    print('a Church, Library, and a Hardware Store. They are spread out within a city and you, a police officer')
    print('has dropped one piece of your gear in each of them. You must retrieve the gear before apprehending')
    print('the bad guy or he will overtake you and you will lose the game. The gear consists of')
    print('handcuffs for restraining the bad guy, a gun in case the bad guy is armed, bullets for the gun, a')
    print('bulletproof vest to protect you in case you are shot, a flashlight in the event that it is dark,')
    print('your badge to prove that you are a police officer and a radio to call for assistance once the bad')
    print('guy is in custody.')
    firstPath = input('You are in the Police Station and can only move south. Enter 1: ')
    if firstPath == '1':
        print()
        path1()
    elif firstPath != '1':
        print(firstPath)

def path1():
    print()

def path2():
    print()

def path3():
    print()

startGame = input('Would you like to start the game? Y/N: ')
if startGame == 'n' or startGame == 'N':
    print('Maybe next time')
elif startGame == 'y' or startGame == 'Y':
    print(intro)
```

Comment: You aren't *calling* `intro`.

Comment: Thanks. I see it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the function `intro` in the last line. Instead, you are printing the function object. Change the last line to:

```
print(intro())
```

or really just

```
intro()
```

since the function prints text and does not return it.

Comment: Thank you. I've been staring at a screen so long I'm missing the littlest things.